# egrep reports "Invalid character range"

Tags: regex, unix, character

I want to check for malformed urls so I found this regex online:

```
/((([A-Za-z]{3,9}:(?:\/\/)?)(?:[-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)?[A-Za-z0-9.-]+|(?:www.|[-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)[A-Za-z0-9.-]+)((?:\/[\+~%\/.\w-_]*)?\??(?:[-\+=&;%@.\w_]*)#?(?:[\w]*))?)/
```

But the thing is that it outputs me the message 'Invalid character range'. I wonder why.

Comment: Your original title mentioned `egrep -x`. The`-x` option doesn't seem to be relevant to the problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It does not like the `[\w-_]`, where it expects a range "from wordcharacter to underscore".
At least, in my test (searching via regex in np++, i.e. a perl flavor),
the complaint occurs already for this little sub-regex.

Comment: As @Yunnosch mentioned with some addition: all hyphen need to be put at the end in brackets then it probably will be fine that way.

Comment: *all hyphen need to be put at the end in brackets* or at the start. Note that in ElasticSearch, in Lucene regex engine, `-` is treated as a literal char only if it is at the start of the bracket expression.